# Chrome Extension jQuery tablesorter overrides tab content existing tablesorter JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tablesorter

I am doing a Chrome Extention now.
Cause, this extension will modify a TAB table content and then needs resorting.

After I did a research, I find that jQuery tablesorter does not sort the *Modified* table updated by local extension script.

I can do $('table').trigger('update') then rebuild the table using tablesorter **IF** I am doing this in TAB content script.

But the truth is that, my script is in isolated environment, which can not access content script variable or function or object.

If I rebuild the tablesorter in my extension script, the table will responds TWICE, which is silly.

What can I do to solve this problem.  Thanks. Mason.

---

@Darin, I tried your points
  It sitll does NOT WORK.

```
$("#xftw").after($("#pio").clone(0, 0));
$("#pio").eq(0).empty();


$("#pio").tablesorter({
    headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: false
        },
        2: {
            sorter: false
        },
        6: {
            sorter: "digit"
        },
        10: {
            sorter: false
        }
    },
    sortInitialOrder: "desc",
    sortList:[[7,1]],
    textExtraction: function (node) {
        if ($(node).attr("extraction") == "my") return "0" + $(node).find("span").text();
        var $firstNode = $(node).find(":first-child");
        return $firstNode.length <= 0 ? $(node).html() : $firstNode.html()
    },
    debug:true
});

var usersTable = $("#pio");
usersTable.trigger("update")
  .trigger("appendCache")
  .trigger("sorton", [[[6,1], [7,1]]]);
```

Comment: >It sitll does NOT WORK. ... How does it not work? How did you solve it with jssort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuild the table, hide the original table, set your new table that you control in its place.

Or use `.preventDefault()` when you `.trigger`

Or change the `id` or `classname` of the table then work on it and `.trigger`

---

Some rough code on creating a new table based on the old table.

```
function copyTable(){
  var newTRs = [];
  var theTable = $(#tableID);
  var theRows = theTable.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (var i=0; i < theRows.length; i++){
    //you could also evaluate each row here and manipulate it as needed.
    newTRs.push(theRows[i].cloneNode(true));
  }
  return newTRs;
}

function buildNewTable(){
    var allRows = copyTable();
    var newTable = document.createElement('table');

    newTable.appendtherows(allRows);
    oldTable.attr('display','none');//or use a .class to hide old table
    $(newTable).appendTo(oldTablesDiv);
}
```

Comment: I tried both methods. 2nd does not work. 1st, I am struggling, but find that, it does not sort after data updated.

Comment: Is the table really huge? If you recreate the table with your own classname and id then the new table has nothing to do with the old table as far as the DOM is concerned. The script for that page won't see your table. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The table is 200 lines of price, times, rate etc num.  After tried so long, I find that .preventDefault() does not work for sure, cause in chrome extension, event is isolated also.   So your point that recreate a new table should work.  But it will cost me lots effort.

Comment: 200 is not big at all. And it won't be much work to recreate it either. I'll update my answer with some psuedo-code to show you what I mean.

Comment: If that helped you solve your problem click the check mark under the up/down Zero to accept the answer :)

Comment: I still have to work this out.  Anyhow, you give a direction.

Comment: I fixed this problem using jssort.